# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting datetime

Tags: python, string

```
log_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__ , "../../", 'logs'))
log_file_path = os.path.join(log_dir, 'Params.txt' % datetime.strftime(datetime.today(), '%Y%m%d'))
```

I get the following error when I write the above code I don't understand why all of my arguments are strings I am sure. I sense that the problem is in the way I put my space holder but I can't figure it out.

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect `'Params.txt' % datetime.strftime(datetime.today(), '%Y%m%d')` to return?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
log_file_path = os.path.join(log_dir, '%s.txt' % (datetime.strftime(datetime.today(), '%Y%m%d'),))
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do with 'Params.txt' and the date? You seem to want to store the date in the file name? If so, I've set it to take the value returned from datetime, stored it in a tuple, and passed it into the filename.